# Invalid directory name error in shutil.rmtree call in Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows

**My objective:** In the current working directory, if a folder called `temp` exists then delete it and create a new one, else simply create the folder `temp`.Then copy a user entered `filename` from the current working directory to the newly created `temp` folder.

**Problem:** I'm getting `WindowsError at line 8(shutil.rmtree(temp_path))` stating `The directory name is invalid`

```
user_file_name = raw_input('Enter the file name:')

cwd = os.getcwd()

temp_path = cwd + r'\temp'

if os.path.exists(temp_path):
   shutil.rmtree(temp_path)
   os.makedirs(temp_path) 
else:
   os.makedirs(temp_path)

temp_xml_path = temp_path + "\\" + user_file_name
xml_path = cwd + "\\" + user_file_name

shutil.copyfile(xml_path, temp_xml_path)
```

Comment: When creating the path, try using ```os.path.join(temp_path, user_file_name)```.

Comment: Agree with @wnnmaw it is safer to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create paths than trying to append strings. This is also true of other path manipulation, e.g. getting relative paths, traversing directories, etc.

Comment: How about a more descriptive title?

Comment: The other key point about using `os.path.join` is that it's a portable method that will work for all OSes so it gets around the various different path conventions

Comment: @AndyG You can suggest a better title if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid a lot of potential issues by using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to create your paths.  What the function does is automatically insert the OS's path delimiter between the args.  Since the delimeter is `\` on Windows, you can make your life much easier by using it instead of manual string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with backslash escaping. Try doing

```
xml_path.encode("string-escape")
```

and the same for temp_xml_path before passing it to copyfile.

Answer (score -1):

temp_path is with only one \, but it is better to use os.path.join

```
temp_path = cwd + r'\\temp'
```

Comment: indeed I was wrong r'' is a raw string so no need to escape it.